# Globalize.parseFloat in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

When I try to parse a float number , the value is getting change .
I try to parse `888888888888888.52` using `Globalize.parseFloat` but value become `888888888888888.50`

Please help

Comment: Why have you tagged it with C#? And if you are using a library you should tag (or at least mention) that library. Also, some relevant code would be useful

Comment: same behavior observed in c# also

Comment: So what C# library are you using that has `Globalize.parseFloat`? And what javascript library are you using?

Comment: Latest jquery Library

Comment: You are using the latest JQuery library in C#? I don't think so... you need to make your question more clear. If this is an issue with `Globalize.parseFloat` then link the reference (because I cannot see it in any version of JQuery) and show example code of how you are using it. If this is just some generic parsing round error, then the `Globalize.parseFloat` is not relevant. And if you also have an issue in C#, then post some sample C# code that replicates the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`888888888888888.52` contains 17 significant digits which is way too much for a double precision floating point number (IEEE754).

It only provides guarantees to keep 15 significant digits correct.

What it means for you: you just cannot represent such a long number precisely using the native JS `Number` scalar data type.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats (see the "Decimal digits" column for "Double precision")

Comment: Well done on teaching a new user the valuable lesson of 'ask a crappy question, still get an answer'...

Comment: @musefan I don't see why it's "crappy". An OP observes something "strange" with a floating point number that can be explained easily, not sure what I've done wrong by doing that.

Comment: @zerkms: It's incorrectly tagged (granted, not a massive issue), it contains very little information about what the OP is doing, it shows no code to replicate the issue (which is my close vote), and it mentions a function that is neither referenced or actually even the reason for the error. Can you argue something that is 'good' about the question?

Comment: @musefan you don't need any code to diagnose the problem: the values is enough. You don't need any code to replicate the issue as soon as you know the nature of the problem (and if you don't - you are not qualified to determine it anyway). I don't see any problems you mentioned.

Comment: The question specifically mentions `Globalize.parseFloat`, this is obviously a function of a library not referenced in the question. Now I am not denying you have supplied the correct answer, but why should it be assumed that the problem is a floating point issue? How can we know that this 'unknown' library doesn't have it's own data type that handle large decimal numbers? For all we know, the rounding error could simple be due to the OP unknowingly passing a parameter to the function that tells it to round to 1 decimal place.

Comment: @musefan indeed, OP should have mentioned what they use initially. So I can count that as an "issue". You still can google it by name.

Comment: @zerkms : you are absolutely correct. same issue observed in Microsoft Excel also. Thank once again

Comment: @zerkms: All I am saying is it's not a well asked question by far, I don't argue that it is answerable, and I don't doubt that you have provided the correct answer. It is a good answer, but that doesn't excuse the question. I just wanted to encourage the OP to improve on question asking, but OP obviously doesn't care for my comments, and now they have the answer they will be even less inclined to do so

Comment: @musefan agree. It's still much better than "where is error in these 1000 lines" or "how to convert this python to clojure" :-)